# find ID of previous button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to find the id of the previous button. It is pretty far away - lots of table rows, tables, divs, etc. between the target and the button but I thought this would still work:

```
alert( $(this).prevAll("input[type=button]").attr('id') );
```

Unfortunately this returns alerts 'undefined'. Help?

Comment: Very first button  id or all buttons ids? And also if you can post some HTML it might be helpful..

Comment: `prev` and `prevAll` will only look at siblings of the selected element. Can you show your HTML structure?

Comment: prevAll looks only at previous siblings.  It will work if the target is actually a sibling.  We could help better if you post the actual HTML.

Comment: `prevAll` only return the siblings that are before the node.

Comment: hmm this definitely is not a sibling. pretty far up on the DOM tree. .parents or .closest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getPrevInput(elem){
    var i = 0,
        inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
        ret = 'Not found';
    while(inputs[i] !== elem || i >= inputs.length){
        if(inputs[i].type === 'button'){
            ret = inputs[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return (typeof ret === 'string') ? ret : ret.id;
}
```

That probably isn't the most efficient solution, but it's the only one I can think of. What it does is goes through all the `input` elements and finds the one right before the one you passed into the function. You can use it like this, assuming you're calling it correctly and `this` is the input element:

```
getPrevInput(this);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nvXFx/3)

Comment: OP was asking for previous button, not the any previous input element. This is almost there

Comment: this worked, but literally turned up the fans on my box. I'm going to select this as the answer but I'm going to put the information I need much closer in the DOM to make a closest() solution doable. Thanks

Comment: @JuanMendes Don't know how I missed that. Fixed.

Comment: Just to be really anal, if there are no buttons before the current one, you will be returning `'Not Found'.id` which is actually really interesting since you're returning a property of a literal string, which is not allowed. However, JS boxes your string, and checks for a property called `id` which is undefined.

Comment: @JuanMendes Damn. I'm not using my head. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 2):

That kind of lookup might be expensive. What about doing a select for all your input[type=button] elements, and traversing that array until you find the element matching your id. Then you can simply reference the array index - 1 to get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is the previous button a sibling of the current button? If not, `prevAll()` won't work. The description of `prevAll()`:

> Get all preceding siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Depending on your DOM structure, you can use a combination of `parents()` and then followed by `find()`.

Comment: As suggested by other users, posting the DOM structure might be useful.

Comment: @themerlinproject: Maybe think about a different way to solve your issue: do you really need to pivot from the current button? If possible, you may traverse from a different node. Just a thought...

Answer (score 1):

This function looks up all `input[type=button]` elements and uses the jQuery `index` function to find your current element in this group.
If it could be found and there is a previous element it is returned.

```
$.fn.previousElem = function(lookup){
    var $elements = $(lookup),
        index = $elements.index(this);
    if(index > 0){
       return $elements.eq(index-1)
    }else{
      return this;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div><div><div><div>
    <input type=button id=1 value=1 />
</div></div></div></div>

<div><div><div><div>
    <input type=button id=2 value=2 />
</div></div></div></div>
```

JS:

```
alert ($("#2").previousElem('input[type=button]').attr('id'))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SnScQ/1/

Comment: This does the job as he's asking, but don't try to make a plugin of it. This won't work if you're looking for a previous element that is of a different type.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different version of Amaan's code, but jqueryfied and his solution wasn't looking for a button. The key to the solution is that jQuery returns the elements in document order, as do `document.getElementsByTagName` and similar functions.

```
var button = $('#c');
var prevNode;
$("input[type=button]").each(function() {
    if (this == button[0]) {
      return false;
    }
    prevNode = this;
});
alert(prevNode && prevNode.getAttribute('id'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/crFy6/

Answer (score 1):

have you tried .closest? ...

```
alert( $(this).closest("input[type=button]").attr('id') );
```